# ie7 permission denied canvas_proxy.php

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer-7

In IE7 I get this JavaScript error when using my Facebook app which is working on all other browsers...

> ie7 permission denied canvas_proxy.php

I'm using https.

Does anyone experiencing such problem?

Comment: The problem is only occur when Im using FB._https = true; flag!